# How to get a select button in command field working in grid view

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I am creating a medication ordering website that is a prototype and holds made up data for a project using asp.net and vb. Patients, doctors and medicines are already recorded on the database. The patient logs in, sees their own medication (through a session - this is displayed on a grid) and I have added a select button - When the button is selected I want the medicine to update on the order table (also recording the date ordered).

There is a patient table and also a medicine table - the patient is linked to their medicine through a link table (prescription table) two composite keys. Once the user is logged in they are redirected to the user.aspx page -

The code to display the logged user's medicine from the database when logged in:

```
Sub Page_Load(ByVal Sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        Dim conn As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Laura\Final_proj\App_Data\surgerydb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30")
        Dim cmdstring As String = "SELECT md.Name, md.Purpose, md.Instrcutions  " +
                                    "FROM Patient pt INNER JOIN prescription pr ON pt.PatientId = pr.PatientId  " +
                                    "INNER JOIN medicine md ON md.MedicineId = pr.MedicineId Where pt.PatientId  = @PatientId"
        Dim dt As New System.Data.DataTable()
        Dim da As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmdstring, conn)
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@PatientId", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(Session("PatientId").ToString())
        conn.Open()
        da.Fill(dt)
        conn.Close()

        GridView1.DataSource = dt
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End If

End Sub
```

This shows the following:

[image: logged in]

I have added a new column to the grid in aspx in order to get the select buttons to appear - these are the buttons I want to correspond with the row and selected medication:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" >
   <Columns>
     <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />

   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The selected information should update here once the medicine from the table is selected (I will then display this table on another page once it is updated):

[image: order]

If I need to provide any more information to help with the question please ask. thankyou

error experienced:

[image]

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: When the button is selected I want the medicine to update on the order table  I have tried but unable to get this to work

Comment: It would be in the button click event.

Comment: @sean lange - The command field select button I have added just through the grid - do I have to do anything to it do it so it recognizes it is selecting a the medicine from the row or will it automatically be connected to the row

Comment: do you have any example code to show this?

Comment: There literally thousands of examples all over the internet for how to use command buttons in a grid.

Comment: my main question above is - is the select column I have added to the grid going to automatically connect with the row - as you can see above I have inserted the table information from a table in my database using a session then I have added another column to the gird - can you please point me in the right direction as this can help me and others to follow :)

Comment: Like I said this is extremely common and there are thousands of examples. It is very well documented how to use command buttons. https://www.google.com/search?q=dotnet+use+command+button+in+grid&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: Please let me know what medical facilities will be using your software.  :)

Comment: Tony - none this is just a webiste im creating to improve my learning of asp.net an vb

Comment: Sean I have tried googling, havnt found a solution to help and been on this issue now for a few days - I am a beginner. The reason why I posted this question was for help and to help those with similar questions.

Comment: Did you click the link to google? It isn't just a smart a$$ answer. It is search link that will take you directly to hundreds of answers to your problem here. The top two responses there should solve the riddle for you.

Comment: yes I have tried but I am so lost :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add the field `MedicineId` to the data source, you can include the LinkButton in a TemplateField and set its `CommandArgument` to the `MedicineID` value:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Select" CommandName="UpdateMedicine" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("MedicineId") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Purpose" HeaderText="Purpose" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Instrcutions" HeaderText="Instructions" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Then you process the `RowCommand` event in code-behind:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowCommand(sender As Object, e as GridViewCommandEventArgs)
    If e.CommandName = "UpdateMedicine" Then
        Dim medecineID As Integer = Integer.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString())
        // Update the data in the database
        ...
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by adding medicineId in the datasource?

Comment: Your `Select` command returns three values (md.Name, md.Purpose, md.Instrcutions). You can add `md.MedicineId` to the list.

Comment: I updated my answer to show how you can specify the fields that you want to see in the GridView (with `BoundField`). Please note `AutoGenerateColumn="false"` in the GridView declaration.

Comment: If I change my gridview lik this will this effect the session (what the user sees when logged in) - the grid is reading from my patient, medicine and the link table between them on my database

Comment: It should look like the `Please select your medication` image in your question. The best way to find out is to try it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114867/discussion-between-laurajs-and-connorsfan).

Comment: Hi @ConnorsFan when I debug the message appears to be " An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException Occurred" on the line- `da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@PatientId", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(Session("PatientId").ToString())`    as seen on the error image above, How can I correct this?

Comment: Hi Laura, we can go back to the chat room. :-)

Comment: Hi @ConnorsFan - could you come back in the room for a little moment please?

Comment: Hi @ConnorsFan - I appear to be getting the error ` Error 1 'GridView1_RowCommand' is not a member of 'ASP.pages_user_aspx  now - how can I fix this?

Comment: Hi Laura, did you include `GridView1_RowCommand` in code-behind, as suggested in the answer? It must be marked as `Protected` or `Public`.

Comment: its disappeared  there - but I am having another major problem - I have moved my project to my computer at college - when I log in my `Dim conn As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\surgerydb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30")
            Dim cmdstring As String = "SELECT md.MedicineId, md.Name, `   is not running  I havnt changed anything over the past few days and to ensure it worked I changed to connect to the database in college

Comment: it reads the `  Using conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\surgerydb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30") `  from my login and redirects the user to the user page

Comment: but `  Dim cmdstring As String = "SELECT md.MedicineId, md.Name, md.Purpose, md.Instrcutions, DoctorId  " +
                                        "FROM Patient pt INNER JOIN prescription pr ON pt.PatientId = pr.PatientId  " +
                                        "INNER JOIN medicine md ON md.MedicineId = pr.MedicineId Where pt.PatientId  = @PatientId" `         - will not display in the grid that previously worked before

Comment: It may be the connection string, I don't know. You can set a breakpoint in the code (F9) and follow the execution step by step with F10 to see where things go wrong.

Comment: I have tried this and does not display any concerns :(- this worked previously

Comment: If you have a breakpoint on this line `GridView1.DataSource = dt`, you can add a watch for `dt` and see how many rows or items it contains. You could also try to run the select query directly in the database engine to see if it returns the expected records.

Comment: I will try this Connorsfan :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115325/discussion-between-laurajs-and-connorsfan).